# Add DIV Element to Layout of the Header

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Having a problem, that I need to add a Element to the NavigationBar in the Header for styling purposes

[image: Code of the problem]

I would need to have

```
<header>
    <cx-pagelayout>
        <div>
            <cx-pageslot>
```

The only option I see is to overwrite the storefront component but i would like to not overwrite a main component. Is there any other option that I not see?

Answer (score 2):

I can see two ways of going about it.

- Like you mentioned you could create your own storefront component and create a header with the DOM you want there.
- You can use the [outlets mechanism](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/outlets) to replace the header with your custom component. This would look something like this:

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="cx-header">
  <custom-header></custom-header>
</ng-template>
```

**or** use the `provideOutlet` provider in your custom header's module like so:

```
  providers: [
    provideOutlet({
      id: 'cx-header',
      position: OutletPosition.REPLACE,
      component: CustomHeaderComponent,
    }),
  ],
```

In the above example, `custom-header` (CustomHeaderComponent) is your header component. Also note, you need to import the `OutletRefModule` in your module.

**Note, if you use the HTML method**: to override the header outlet, you need to put your OutletRef in the `app.component.html`